# How to concatenate all the mapped nodes in a .xslt file with a string or character?

Tags: xslt

How to concatenate all the mapped nodes in a XSLT file with a string or character?  For example, every node value should be prefixed and suffixed with single quote characters.

Comment: Do you have a particular XSLT file? What kind of output (XML, HTML, plain text) does it create? What is a "mapped node", what do you consider a "node value"?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the xml input and the xslt you have so far? Your question will be much easier to answer with something for me to look at. I've written xslt to concatenate nodes, but the specifics are important.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for all your comment. Actual problem is, I have a transformation which populating correct output. Using this output I have to create a .csv file. But if any of the node value contains comma(,) value then the .csv file is not generating properly. The column values are treated as separate and column values are shifting. So as a solution for this, I have to keep all the node values inside the quotes ''. Looking for a solution may be a template which can can concatenate values within quotes. For example.

Comment: For Example:   
   <invoiceNumber>supplierInvoiceNum13255</invoiceNumber>
      <invoiceAmount>invoiceAmount13259</invoiceAmount>
      <invoiceDate>invo/ic/eD</invoiceDate>
      <description>sfsfdfdfdfg</description>
   
   Should be transformed  like
   
   <invoiceNumber>'supplierInvoiceNum13255'</invoiceNumber>
      <invoiceAmount>'invoiceAmount13259'</invoiceAmount>
      <invoiceDate>'invo/ic/eD'</invoiceDate>      
      <description>'sfsfdfdfdfg'</description>

Answer (score 0):

With the information you provided in your question:

> For example, every node value should be prefixed and suffixed with single quote characters.

One of the way can be using function **concat()** and making variable for single quote (`&quot;`) as below:

```
<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($apos,'The value to populate',$apos)"/>
```

It should be modified further based on your 'mapped nodes' implementation

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The solution is correct for transforming a single node value. But I need to apply same for all the nodes in xslt except empty values. Please help.